# How can I use foreach function well?

Tags: r

I would like to use `foreach()` function in R.

Here's my example code.

```
library(randomForestSRC)
library(dplyr)
library(ROCR)
library(doParallel)

data(pbc, package="randomForestSRC")

data_na <- na.omit(pbc)
data_na <- data_na %>% dplyr::select(-days)

foreach(VAR=age) %do% {
  data_na <- data_na %>%
    mutate(Q4 = ifelse(data_na[,"VAR"]<=unname(quantile(data_na[,"VAR"], 0.25)), 0,
                ifelse(data_na[,"VAR"]<=unname(quantile(data_na[,"VAR"], 0.50)), 1,
                ifelse(data_na[,"VAR"]<=unname(quantile(data_na[,"VAR"], 0.75)), 2, 3)))) 
}
```

Without modifying the whole code, I want to change the code

`foreach(VAR=age) or foreach(VAR=bili)..`. etc.

But in the error message, this code consider `"age"` as an object.

How can I run this code without error?

Comment: First put the names of the variables that you want to loop over in a vector:  `varnames <- names(data_na)`.  Then do `foreach(VAR=varnames)...`.  Note however that your code is designed to continually overwrite `data_na` and so this is not something amenable to parallelization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the foreach with `foreach(VAR="age")` and then call as `data_na[,VAR]` instead `data_na[,"VAR"]`.

Also, you can define the vars to the foreach as follow:

```
vars <- c("age", "bili") # you can include more variables here

foreach(i = 1:length(vars)) %do% {
  VAR = vars[i]
  data_na <- data_na %>%
    mutate(Q4 = ifelse(data_na[,VAR]<=unname(quantile(data_na[,VAR], 0.25)), 0,
                       ifelse(data_na[,VAR]<=unname(quantile(data_na[,VAR], 0.50)), 1,
                              ifelse(data_na[,VAR]<=unname(quantile(data_na[,VAR], 0.75)), 2, 3)))) 
}
```